# Trying to deploy an image but getting an error "/var/lib/containerd/tmpmounts/containerd-mount887356499/etc/passwd: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am deploying a container on AKS cluster, but getting this error :

```
kubelet, aks-appnodepool1-24784374-vmss00001r  Error: failed to create containerd container: mount callback failed on /var/lib/containerd/tmpmounts/containerd-mount887356499: open /var/lib/containerd/tmpmounts/containerd-mount887356499/etc/passwd: no such file or directory
```

Here is the docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Worker.dll"]
```

Comment: How are you actually trying to deploy it?  What's in, for example, your Kubernetes Deployment manifest YAML file?